# Stop search results showing all records if blank form submitted

Tags: php, sql, forms

When my form gets submitted with some text, everything is fine. But if it's submitted blank, it displays all records. So how do I add the logic - if the form submission is blank, treat it as no results? This is my search-results.php:

```
<?php 

// BY TITLE
if (isset($_POST['submit_search'])) {
$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search']);
    $sql = "SELECT posters.ID, posters.img_detail, posters.movie, movies.title movie FROM posters INNER JOIN movies ON posters.movie = movies.ID WHERE title LIKE '%$search%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    ?>
    
    <?php 
    if ($queryResult == "1") {
    echo "There is ".$queryResult. " result";
    }
    else {
        echo "There are ".$queryResult. " results";
    }
    ?>
    
    </div>
            
    <div class="row">
    <?php 
    if ($queryResult > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
             $i = 1;
    ?>
```

.. and then it echos the results
(Sorry if it's obvious, I'm a newbie)

Comment: An easy fix would be to change `if (isset($_POST['submit_search']))` to `if (empty($_POST['search']) === false)`. Then the query will only be run if `$_POST['search']` (which is the value you really care about) exists and isn't empty. I would also recommend using GET instead of POST for the search form since it's about _GETting_ data, while POST is usually used to send data to be stored.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks

Comment: And thanks for your comments re post/get

Answer (score 0):

Use the [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function to check if your `$_POST['search']` is empty before running the sql.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_search'])) {
   if (empty($_POST['search'])) {
       //run search
   }
}
```

Comment: I had tried that earlier and couldn't get it to work - will try again.